# Time comparison trouble with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, logic

I have a very simple task at hand.  If the last time a record was updated has been longer than 15 minutes, display a button.  Otherwise, don't display the button.

The field is a datetime.

My view code:

```
<% if @object.display_button? -%>
  my button
<% end -%>
```

My display button method on that object:

```
def display_button?
  return false if last_updated.nil?
  if Time.now - last_updated > 15.minutes
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I also have this unit tested, which are passing, but when it comes to the implementation, it doesn't seem to work.

Is my logic correct or would there be a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if last_updated < 15.minutes.ago
```

The minutes method returns an integer I believe, and subtracting time object yields another time object.  So your expression compares an int to a time and does something that you dont expect.

`15.minutes.ago` yields a time object that can be directly compared to another time object.

---

Also, never ever do `if (something) return true; else; return false` in ruby.  Your method will return the value of that last expression executed in it, so you can vastly simplify that entire method:

```
def display_button?
  last_updated && last_updated < 15.minutes.ago
end
```

Isn't that easier to read?

Comment: is `last_updated` a time object?  I was assuming it was.  Go to script/console and type in "15.minutes.ago", you should get a time object back like "Tue, 24 Feb 2009 16:46:05 UTC +00:00".  So be sure that last_updated is a time object too.  Look at Time#since and Time#until too to calculate these.

Comment: What's odd, is if I use this display_button method in the console, I return my true/false just fine when manually setting that object attribute, but inside the view, nothing changes.  Will keep poking around.

Comment: You probably also want to define the display_button? method in a Helper, not in the Model, since the Model doesn't really care whether a button is displayed.  So something like "def display_button?(model)..."